# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2) -- whats the problem with this?

Tags: 13.04, apt, package-management, dpkg

error when installing any packages.. pls help.. thanks in advance..

been trying to solve this for days now.. still can't solve it.. Already tried

```
    $ sudo apt-get update
    $ sudo apt-get upgrade
    $ sudo apt-get autoremove
    $ sudo apt-get clean
```

`etc..`

```
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package libglade2-0:amd64.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'linux-headers-3.8.0-19': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: Comment you Ubuntu version and the packages what you were trying to install. Try this command and paste the result here: `uname -a`

Comment: Linux dreamer-ubuntu 3.8.0-29-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 13 19:40:39 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux -- thats the result after uname -a @Saurav Kumar

Comment: you can try steps described in this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies It is really a goot link to solve such issues.

Comment: thanks I will try it.. and come back here if it is fixed..

Comment: Yes of course.. and also execute this command: `lsb_release -a` and paste your output.

Comment: No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 13.04
Release: 13.04
Codename: raring